# Modify query function so it can work as an arrayformula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How do I modify this equation so I can use it with an array function instead of dragging it down.

```
SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(", ", UNIQUE(QUERY(A:D,"SELECT B WHERE C = '"&G2&"'"))), ", , ", "")
```

Explanation of the equation:

Have a function is used to extract and concatenate unique values from column B of a sheet named A:D, where the values in column C match a specific criteria. The function is made up of several parts:

It uses the QUERY function to extract all values from column B of sheet A:D where the values in column C match the specific criteria in G.

UNIQUE removes any duplicate values from previous step.

JOIN to concatenate into a single string separated by a comma to returns a string of unique values that match the criteria

SUBSTITUTE to replace occurrences of ", , " with an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try:

```
=BYROW(G2:G,LAMBDA(gx,IF(gx="",,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,C:C=gx)))))))
```

Comment: how did you figure it out? I must wait 3 minutes to accept.